# Internet not working after updating to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: internet, settings, 23.04

After updating my Ubuntu 22.04LTS to 23.04 my internet stopped working. It is connected to Wi-Fi but taking no data.
Also the settings application is not working.

Comment: Please add information to your original posting for questions in comments.  In a terminal, does ping 8.8.8.8 work? (shows an internet connection).  Do you have an ipv4 ip and no ipv6 from your ifconfig output? (I usually disable ipv6 at the wifi connection setting to avoid confusion). Can you ping google.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it did help me to solve a resolve issue with Ubuntu 20.04

rm -f /etc/resolv.conf

ln -sv /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. It seems it had to do with IP leasing, even though the machine was still able to lease an IP address but could not connect to the internet.

I used the following to fix the internet connection issue then pull the new gnome-* packages that caused the crashes.

```bash
sudo dhclient
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```